# QGIS - setting a default value on geometry column

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Using the QGIS interface it's not possible to set a default value expression on the geometry column. However, it's clearly possible to calculate geometries using expressions. The geometry column is selectable in the Field calculator.
The PyQGIS function setDefaultValueExpression asks for a field index but I can't seem to find the index of the geometry column. Is there some other way to automatically set geometries on newly added features?

My use case is fairly simple, I'm adding rows to a child table and want new features to have the same geometry as the parent feature.